# Need to get formated output C#

Tags: c#, command-line, console

I need to create a console application to print some help messages.I have done that but it does not show the results in the default tabular format in console like,

```
c:\Users\>dir /?
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
  /C          Display the thousand separator in file sizes.  This is the
              default.  Use /-C to disable display of separator.
  /D          Same as wide but files are list sorted by column.
  /L          Uses lowercase.
  /N          New long list format where filenames are on the far right.
  /O          List by files in sorted order.
  sortorder    N  By name (alphabetic)       S  By size (smallest first)
               E  By extension (alphabetic)  D  By date/time (oldest first)
               G  Group directories first    -  Prefix to reverse order
  /P          Pauses after each screenful of information.
```

Do i need to use escape sequences or is there any inbuilt function to display like this.I googled it.But unable to find solution can any one help:)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 1):

In this very specific case, simply put the content in a text file, and write to the console stream the content of the text file.

I would put the text file as a resource to simplify the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use [@-quoted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) string literal.

```
string help = @"
Usage of @-quoted literal:
  1. Escape sequences are not processed
  2. To include double quotes then ""double it""
";
Console.WriteLine(help);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use spaces to format the output.

```
Console.WriteLine("DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]]");
Console.WriteLine("  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]]");
```